# UILabel position in custom tableView cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to make an app without using storyboards and I have a problem.
I've set up custom cell and everything looks ok on iPhone 5s:
[image]

But my right label looks wrong on, for example, iPhone 6s+:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {


var leftLabel = UILabel()
var currencyValueLabel = UILabel()



required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
}


override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    leftLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(
            x: 16,
            y: 8,
            width: 100,
            height: self.bounds.size.height-16
        ))
        leftLabel.textAlignment = .Left
        addSubview(leftLabel)

    currencyValueLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(
            x: self.bounds.size.width-116,
            y: 8,
            width: 100,
            height: self.bounds.size.height-16
        ))
        rightLabel.textAlignment = .Right
        addSubview(rightLabel)

}


}
```

**Update:**
I've tried autolayout:

```
leftLabel.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.layoutMarginsGuide.leadingAnchor, constant: 20).active = true
    leftLabel.centerYAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(self.layoutMarginsGuide.centerYAnchor).active = true
```

and this is result

```
    2016-05-05 18:49:09.849 RubApp[57636:2228350] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503d21c50 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7fc503cea100'EUR'.midX == + 66>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503d1ea40 h=--& v=--& H:[UILabel:0x7fc503cea100'EUR'(100)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503ce7c00 UILabel:0x7fc503cea100'EUR'.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x7fc503ce8c20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading + 20>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503ce98e0 h=-&- v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[RubApp.MainViewCell:0x7fc505868000'idTableCellMainView']   (Names: '|':UITableViewWrapperView:0x7fc505869600 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503ce7df0 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(15)-[UILayoutGuide:0x7fc503ce8c20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (Names: '|':RubApp.MainViewCell:0x7fc505868000'idTableCellMainView' )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503ce7c00 UILabel:0x7fc503cea100'EUR'.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x7fc503ce8c20'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading + 20>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2016-05-05 18:49:09.857 RubApp[57636:2228350] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
    (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503e5a720 h=--& v=--& UILabel:0x7fc503e49b50'USD'.midX == + 66>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503e5a940 h=--& v=--& H:[UILabel:0x7fc503e49b50'USD'(100)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503e56f50 UILabel:0x7fc503e49b50'USD'.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x7fc503e4a3a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading + 20>",
    "<NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503e5ab70 h=-&- v=--& 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Left' H:|-(0)-[RubApp.MainViewCell:0x7fc504030a00'idTableCellMainView']   (Names: '|':UITableViewWrapperView:0x7fc505869600 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503e4a780 'UIView-leftMargin-guide-constraint' H:|-(15)-[UILayoutGuide:0x7fc503e4a3a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'](LTR)   (Names: '|':RubApp.MainViewCell:0x7fc504030a00'idTableCellMainView' )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7fc503e56f50 UILabel:0x7fc503e49b50'USD'.leading == UILayoutGuide:0x7fc503e4a3a0'UIViewLayoutMarginsGuide'.leading + 20>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKit/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
```

I know that something wrong with constant setting, but don't know what. Sorry if this question is stupid but this is my first app without storyboards.

Comment: so is there a reason you aren't using auto-layout ?

Comment: FYI - you have  a typo (which is why you should always copy and paste your code). You create `currencyValueLabel` but then reference it as `rightLabel`.

Comment: @Wain I've updated my question. Can you help me with autolayouts?

Comment: @rmaddy I've replaced currencyValueLabel to rightLabel only for the question, in app all references is ok

Comment: You don't need auto layout for something this simple. Just add the one line of code shown in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to add this line just before `addSubview(rightLabel)`:

```
rightLabel.autoresizingMask = .FlexibleLeftMargin
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an `NSLayoutConstraint` telling the label on the right hand side to have a trailing constraint of x.

Comment: I've updated my question. Can you help me with autolayouts?

Comment: I assume you no longer need this, as the question has been answered, but if you want me to show you the correct code, it will be my pleasure.